# Is it possible to use Matlab "system" function to call ROS commands?

Tags: mobile-robot, software, ros

Is it possible to use the Matlab's `system` function to call ROS commands?

For example, using `system('rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry.msgs.Twist {....}`
or `system('rospack find ipc_bridge)`.

I'm trying to send some commands to ROS without using something like IPC-Bridge.

PS: I know, however, that I need to use IPC-Bridge to subscribe to topics.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible. But it is very sloppy, in my humble opinion. It is useful for one-off commands, but how will you read back output, verify your command was executed, etc.

If you are dead-set against the IPC bridge, you may want to look at using the [MATLAB-java interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/product-overview.html). ROS also allows you to program in Java using ros-fuerte-client-rosjava (ubuntu), or just [rosjava](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava).

Comment: Ok. Then what am I doing wrong? How can I use the system function properly?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Use it if it works for you. Just be sure to set up your bash environment correctly so your commands work. I can see this as helpful for running a matlab script, which then uses rosparam to set the output of the functions for nodes to read. However, I was referring to how difficult it might be to "close the loop" and use matlab to read from ROS ndoes.